# Excel: Return the last entries from a list of entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please excuse me for the wording of the title. Not sure exactly how to word this so it's probably best to just show.

I have a list that looks like this

Name      Date Updated
====      =========== 
Item 1      1/1/2015 
Item 2      1/2/2015 
Item 3      1/3/2015 
Item 2      1/4/2015 
Item 3      1/5/2015 
Item 1      1/6/2015

This will be an ongoing list. As items are updated they will be entered in like this. I would like to create a second sheet that gives me the last date that each item was updated. So the result based on the above table would look like this.

Name      Date Updated
====      =========== 
Item 1      1/6/2015 
Item 2      1/4/2015 
Item 3      1/5/2015

I have found a few solutions on the web that work when I first input the formula (Links below), BUT when I add more entries in the first table the results wont update or they'll show the wrong data.

Links:
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/02/04/find-last-item-in-group-with-index-match/

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2014/02/07/find-last-matching-value-in-an-unsorted-list/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Links that you have posted is working for your example. I have checked this link: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2014/02/07/find-last-matching-value-in-an-unsorted-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record a macro as you do it manually one time.  Then assign that macro to a button.  Then click the button anytime you need the sheet updated.

Steps:

1. Start on a sheet other than the one with the data.  Explanation in #3 below.
2. Start recording your macro by going to View > Macros > Record Macro.  In the bottom left you'll now see a square stop button for when you want to stop recording.
3. Select the sheet with the data.  This way the macro will always remember to select the right sheet regardless of where you are.
4. Select the two-column range of cells that has your data, then continue selecting a few hundred rows down, or at least well beyond where you think your data will eventually go down to.
5. Copy
6. Select the sheet where you want to have the summarized data.
7. Paste
8. Sort by name (ascending) and date (descending) all at once (rather than two operations).  Do this by going to the Data tab in the ribbon and selecting the white and blue sort button that has two A's and two Z's and says "Sort".
9. With this pasted and sorted range still selected, remove duplicates in the name column.  To do this, do not change the selection.  Go to the Data tab and select Remove Duplicates.
10. Now your items will appear once and the date will be the most recent date.
11. Click the "stop recording" square blue button in the bottom left to stop recording your Macro.
12. You can assign this macro to a button or to a shortcut.  To add a button you need to show the developer tab and then draw the button using one of the options on the developer tab.  I can't remember offhand how to show the developer tab.  Once you have a button, right click and assign the macro to the button.

13A. If you want to customize the macro, click ALT+F11 to get to the visual basic editor.  Double click on one of the things named something like "module" on the left and you can edit your the range in your macro, for example if your data suddenly goes down 100 more rows than what you planned and you want the macro to cover it.  Save with CTRL+S.  The next time you run your macro, it will reflect these changes.

13B. View > Macros to edit your macro if you want to assign a shortcut key to it instead of adding a button.

Try all this with a copy of your spreadsheet so that you don't delete data by accident.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Sounds like it should work. Never thought of going that route. Just need some time here to test it.

Comment: This worked really well! One more quick questions. I wanted to add an "Expiration" date in a cell to the right of the date. The list of "Items" will grow as time goes on. So i figured I could just ad 30 days to the last date it was uploaded but I want to make sure that I cover all future additions in the Macro. Problem is if I add the "Expiration" formula to the macro it adds "1/30/1900" in all of the cells that don't have values to calculate. Is it possible to delete these "blank" cells in the macro? Doing a find and replace using 1/30/1900 date doesn't work because it's created by a formula.

Comment: Try a conditional formula in cell C2 that looks like this: =IF(B2<>"",B2+30,"").  This says that if B2 is not equal to "" (Excel treats that as an empty cell), then have C2 = B2 + 30.  If not, then make the cell blank.
In the macro you can always manually type that into the cell and then drag/copy it down and the macro will do that each time.  If you don't want to record the whole thing again, record just that part and then paste those lines from the new macro (probably in Module 2 now) into the first macro.  Press F8 and you can watch it executing line by line when you're in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit the numbers in the formula to get the whole column:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,MAX(($E$3=$B:$B)*MATCH(ROW($B:$B),ROW($B:$B))))
```

(following the formula from your second link).

Comment: I've tried that. I'm getting "#N/A" Error: "Value Not Available Error"

Comment: If you go in the Formulas tab and go to 'Evaluate Formula', which function is the first one to show an error?

Comment: I think it's the "MATCH"

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with a Pivot Table.  Drag Item to Rows area and Dates to the Values area.  Then format the values as Date, and select to return Max.